# Integration of $\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln x^2 +6\ln x}}$

Tags: integration, substitution

$\require{cancel}$
Hello everybody so this is my integration question. I have reached a point in my picture. I don't know how to continue. I appreciate the help.
Also , am I going in the right direction ??

Please note, square root is over $\ln x^2 +6\ln x$.

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\ln x^2+6\ln x}}dx\underset{\substack{\big| \\ u=\ln t \\ du=\frac{dt}{t}}}{=}{}&\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+6u}}du\underset{\substack{\big| \\ \text{Complete} \\ \text{square.}}}{=}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(u+5)^2-9}}du={} \\
{}\underset{\substack{\big| \\ s=u+5 \\ ds=du}}{=}{}&\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2-9}}ds\underset{\substack{\big| \\ s=3\sec z \\ ds=3\tan z\sec zdz}}{=}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9\sec^2z-9}}3\tan z\sec zdz={} \\
{}\underset{\substack{\big| \\ \sec^2z-1=\tan^2z}}{=}{}&\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9\tan^2z}}dz=\int\frac{3\tan z\sec z}{3\tan z}dz=\int\sec zdz={} \\
{}={}&\int\frac{\sec z(\tan z+\sec z)}{\tan z+\sec z}dz=\int\frac{\cancel{\sec z\tan z}+\sec^2z}{\cancel{\sec z\tan z}}dz=\int\sec^2zdz.
\end{align*}

[Image of work by OP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAWP3.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: Please take the time to type your answer here, rather than posting a photo.

Comment: waste of memory. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: A picture takes up more memory than a few lines of Tex :)

Comment: Typing your work here would also give you a chance to correct the abuse of arrows in the picture. It's nearly at the point where it's not possible to follow your line of thought.

Comment: I included your image. That simplification is just wrong. The right thing would be to get $1+\frac{\sec z}{\tan z}=1+\frac{1}{\sin x}$.

Comment: Usually, $\ln x^2=2\ln x$, which is different from $(\ln x)^2$.

Comment: THANK YOU @MickG thats very helpful!!! I appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. And you should write $(\ln x)^2$ if you mean the square of the logarithm, otherwise I think most people (me included) would take it for the logarithm of the square, as @egreg noted.

Comment: Or you can use $\ln^2x$.

Answer (score 5):

Set $t=\ln x$ and $dt=\frac{dx}{x}$

$$=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+6t}}\overset{\text{complete the square}}{=}\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t+3)^2-9}}$$

Set $s=t+3$ and $ds=dt$

$$=\int\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^2-9}}$$

Set $s=3\sec(p)$ and $ds=3\tan p \sec p dp$, then $\sqrt{s^2-9}=\sqrt{9\sec^2 p-9}=3\tan p$ and $p=\sec^{-1}\left(\frac s 3 \right)$

$$=\int \sec pdp=\ln(\tan p +\sec p)+\mathcal C=\dots$$

Comment: did  that!, check out the image, im stuck at integral of sec^2.

Comment: I'm working on full solution,

Comment: @Nehorai you have an extra 3 in the last line

Comment: Zoom in :). I just copied it anyways. Nice image :P.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the differential in the form $\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s^{2}-a^{2}}}$, the integral will be just the inverse hyperbolic cosine of $\frac sa$ plus a constant.